# Speed up highscore rank calculation

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I calculate a highscore and find the users current rank like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195257/ranking-entries-in-mysql-table). This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT  q.*, @r := @r + 1 AS rank
FROM ( SELECT  @r := 0 ) vars,
(
    SELECT  p.*, MAX(punkte) AS max_points
    FROM olympia_punkte_alle p
    WHERE markt_id = 1
    GROUP BY fb_id
    ORDER BY max_points DESC
) q) AS q2 WHERE fb_id = '26950' ORDER BY max_points DESC LIMIT 1
```

Problem is that the table has many rows (~8,5 Mio) and so this query is very slow. I could cache the sub select but than the highscore is always kind of old.

Any thoughts on how to make this faster?

EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type         table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1352    Using where; Using filesort
2   DERIVED <derived3>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1    
2   DERIVED <derived4>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1352     
4   DERIVED             p       ref     markt_id 4              2055    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    No tables used
```

Comment: Since rank is calculated on the outer query, is it really necessary here? Could this be calculated in php instead.

Comment: @Waygood: You want to load 8,5 millions records to memory in php script?

Comment: After re-reading, the OP just wants the current rank, not a list of rankings, which would have been row number (in php). +1'd @ŁukaszW.pl (you LOL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 as user_rank
    FROM olympia_punkte_alle p
    WHERE markt_id = 1
    GROUP BY fb_id
    HAVING 
        MAX(punkte) > (SELECT MAX(punkte)
            FROM olympia_punkte_alle
            WHERE markt_id = 1
            GROUP BY fb_id
            HAVING fb_id = 2950)
```

We are getting the count of users that have better score then users with id `2950`.
The count of better users + 1 is rank of your user.

Comment: Nice, this query is 1 second faster! But still takes 6 seconds. I am trying to store max_points, that should make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only refactoring that I can come up with:

```
SET @r = 0;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  q.*, @r := @r + 1 AS rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  p.*, MAX(punkte) AS max_points
        FROM olympia_punkte_alle p
        WHERE markt_id = 1
        GROUP BY fb_id
    ) q
    ORDER BY q.max_points DESC
) AS q2
WHERE fb_id = '26950'
LIMIT 0,1
```

A possible caching optimization that you could implement is to add a `max_points` column in some users table somewhere. Then every time a user changes his score, you calculate `MAX(punkte)` and store that in the `max_points` column. That way you could save time calculating the maximum points for every query. It would end up something like:

```
SET @r = 0;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT u.*, @r := @r + 1 AS rank
    FROM users u
    ORDER BY u.max_points DESC
) AS q
WHERE q.fb_id = '26950'
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: Storing max_points is a great idea. Thank you!